# Similarity of two texts (adaptive local alignment of keywords?)

Tags: algorithm, similarity

I have 2 texts (max 4000 characters) of different length. And I need to get a similarity rate based on (partial-)paraphrasing. Please note that same portion of texts can be in different position in each text (So **Levenshtein** is not the solution).

The comparison process should also:

- not increase expo. with text size
- be performance friendly. :)

It seems that the "**adaptive local alignment of keywords**" is a possible solution.

Do you have any implementation example? Preferred language is PHP but I can translate. :)

Do you have any other solution/idea/experience on that topic?

Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `levenshtein` and `similar_text` functions which should make your life easier:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

EDIT: @Toto has pointed out that those may not be suitable for this application, see his comments below.

Comment: levenshtein is not the solution in this case. Take the 2 sequences : 'ABC' and 'BCA'. Replace each (same) letter by a (same) word, (same) phrase or (same) paragraph. The edit distance is high even if it is a only an order difference. Also Levenshtein is a killer (on performance level).

Comment: similar_text seems to be also an edit distance base on the char level... => not the solution...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (My question was not really clear. Sorry for the confusion). :))

Comment: @Toto - what a fool I am, I didn't even realize that it's your question :)

Comment: No no you read it correctly the first time. I edited the text to remove the confusion after I saw everybody was proposing the levenshtein solution. :)

Comment: If I understand you, you'd like to include rearrangement operations into the similarity matches?

Answer (score 0):

[Needleman-Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm) worked quite well for an application where I had to match names given to the same thing by different people.